# Loop .click Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to figure out how to loop a .click function with the slideToggle.
Here's the code for the single event:

```
$("#slide1").click(function () {
  $("#panel1").slideToggle(1000);
});
```

slide1 is the div the person would click on toggling the panel to slide down or up.
I've tried a for loop and etc to figure out how to loop this for multiple slide's and panels.

Say I have 10 slides is it possible to create one loop for all 10 or does it have to be done individually?

Comment: Are you trying to create a click event for every slide or have one click loop through all the panels ?

Comment: Sorry a click event for every slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). This will handle any events for any of the children. The first argument is a filter for which children you want to listen to. In this case you only want to capture events for `.slide`s. The second argument specifies the type of event you want to listen to, here you need `click` as you only need click events. The last argument is the handler. In this handler function `this` refers to the element that has been clicked on.

```js
$('#container').delegate('.slide', 'click', function(event) {
  $($(this).data('toggle')).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #AAA;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
.panel {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #44A;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="slide" data-toggle="#panel1">Toggle panel 1</div>
  <div class="slide" data-toggle="#panel2">Toggle panel 2</div>
  <div class="slide" data-toggle="#panel3">Toggle panel 3</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel1">Panel 1</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel2">Panel 2</div>
  <div class="panel" id="panel3">Panel 3</div>
</div>
```

You can add as many slides and panels as you want (also dynamically), `delegate` will handle any click events on a `.slide`.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The tidy way of doing this:

```
<div class="slide" data-panel="panel1">...</div>
<div id="panel1">...</div>
```

Build your slides like that. Then one handler is all you need:

```
$(".slide").click(function() {
    $("#"+this.getAttribute("data-panel")).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in a more dynamic way:

```
$(".slide").click(function() {
  $("#"+$(this).attr("data-panel")).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

I hope that helps, good luck